# How to switch on/off RFID using piezo sensor?

Tags: rfid, piezo

I need to connect a piezo sensor to a RFID tag such that when someone presses on the piezo, the voltage generated activates the tag. A nearby RFID reader continuously looks for the tag. The tag remains off/undetectable while the piezo sensor is not touched.

Can I achieve this by removing the antenna on a RFID tag and connecting the terminals to a piezo sensor? The voltage spike can from my piezo sensor can be up to 10 volts. Should I try to limit it before connecting it to the RFID chip.

Also I need this in low latency i.e. small time gap between touch/un-touching piezo and that activating/deactivating tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved by modifying the antenna path. Instead you should probably detect the press and turn the entire circuit on/off.

If instead of a piezo element, you use capacitive touch then you can use off-the-shelf components and circuitry. For example dedicated capacitive touch IC like TPP223-BA6, or AVR AtTiny microcontroller with QTouch library.